# USB file not showing on Mac Desktop

Tags: mac, windows, disk-utility, usb, monterey

I have a 4.0 GB USB formatted as NTFS that didn’t appear on my Mac so I tried it on Windows and changed the format to ExFAT.

I added files and tried it on my Mac, but it did not mount or show up in Disk Utilitiesl

I can not figure out what the issue is. My plugs and ports are all working even the USB lights up so I can see that it is working and being used on the Windows PC and having files added I know it works.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get my USB to show and work on my Mac.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of `Disk Utility` after you have connected the drive to your Mac and selected `View > Show All Devices`

Comment: In case this is a hardware issue: What brand and model USB thing? How are you connecting to your Mac? what Mac model?

Comment: In the first sentence do you mean 'format' where you twice say 'file'?